# Populate data without association id in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, join, sequelize.js, associations

I have 4 tables, user, profile , speciality , user_specialities. I am using sequelize. My user model is-->

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
user_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
    },
    IsDeleted: {
        type:Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    },
    status: {
        type:Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
},
});
```

My profiles model-->

```
const Profile= sequelize.define('profile', {
    profile_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
    },
    first_name: {
        type:Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    last_name: {
        type:Sequelize.STRING,
    },
},
{
    indexes: [
        {
            unique: true,
            fields: ['user_id']
        }
    ]
});   
Chef_Info.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: 'user_id'});
```

Speciality table-->

```
    const Profile= sequelize.define('speciality', {
        speciality_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
        },
        title: {
            type:Sequelize.STRING,
        },
}
```

user_specialities hold the many to many relation between user and speciality. I have used `belongsToMany` association like this -

```
Speciality.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'user_speciality',foreignKey: 'speciality_id', otherKey: 'user_id'});
User.belongsToMany(Speciality, {through: 'user_speciality',foreignKey: 'user_id', otherKey: 'speciality_id'});
```

Now, I want to get data where I have user_id, first_name, last_name also the specialities. For example-->

```
first_name  | last_name     | specialities
Khabib      | Nurmagamedov  | Athlete, Wrestler
Tony        | Ferguson      | Athlete, Striker
```

I tried in MySql, where query should be-->

```
SELECT profiles.first_name,profiles.last_name,GROUP_CONCAT(specialities.title)
FROM (
users
    LEFT JOIN profiles
         ON users.user_id = profiles.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN user_specialities
        ON users.user_id = user_specialities.user_id
    LEFT JOIN specialities
        ON chef_specialities.speciality_id = specialities.speciality_id
)
WHERE(
    AND users.IsDeleted = false
    And users.status = true
)
GROUP BY users.user_id;
```

But I am struggling to convert this to sequelize. I have come this far-->

```
UserSpecialities.findAll({
    attributes:[sequelize.fn('GROUP_CONCAT', sequelize.col('title')), 'speciality_id'],
    include: [
    { 
       model: User,
       attributes: [],
       where:{
           IsRemoved: false,
           status: true,
       },
    },
    { model: Speciality,
         attributes: [],
    },
    ],
    group:['user_id']
```

Its provides the specialities userwise-->

```
[
    {
        "speciality_id": "Athlete, Wrestler",
    },
    {
        "speciality_id": "Athlete, Striker",
    }
]
```

But I am failing to populate the profile data here.If I try to include profile, it shows no association error, or I try to add a `hasMany`in user model it throws error again. What should I do in this situation? 
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Profile is associated with Users but not UserSpecialties it would make more sense to accomplish this with two queries.

Grab your user specialties like you did above, then take those userId's and grab their associated profiles (should be something like `User.getProfile` depending on how your associations are set up).

Right now you have your UserSpecialties attributes set up to only return the specialty_id and title, if you add in userId to those attributes then you can use those userId's to query your profile table. A then promise works well for something like this so something like:

```
UserSpecialties.findAll({...}).then((userSpecialties) => {
  User.getProfile({where: {userId: userSpecialties.userId}, attributes: {'first_name', 'last_name'})
});
```

Depending on what you are specifically trying to do with the information you will probably have to tweak it a bit, but the general idea of adding in userId as an attribute and then querying your User table for profiles using the userId from the UserSpecialties query result should work fine for the data you want.

Though looking at your models, it might make sense to just have profile and user be one table, where User has first_name, last_name, userId, and status. Since Profile doesn't have a lot of other stuff to it, and then if you need specific things for the userProfile you can use scopes on your user model.